# The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type

Tags: android, fragment, expandablelistview

I get the error

> The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type PM_section

when trying to implement my Expandable ListView. I am sure this is a common error, but I am having trouble finding a solution. I am attempting to learn fragments and such, and it has been an uphill battle ever since I started. I have done a fair bit of searching, and found a lot of results, that don't seem to help me in my case.

If someone could give me any insight, or point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

My small test class is below

```
public class PM_section extends Fragment {
//  CustomExpListView custExpListView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pm_section_test, container, false);

        CustomExpListView custExpListView = (CustomExpListView)
                this.findViewById(R.id.ExpandableListView01);
        return V;   
    }// end on create
}
```

The CustomExpListView class was pretty much copy, pasted from the Android Sample Projects, and is happy and has no problems.

Thanks you for helping me out.

Answer (score 10):

If `R.id.ExpandableListView01` is part of `R.layout.fragment_pm_section_test`, then replace `this` with `V`.

```
CustomExpListView custExpListView = (CustomExpListView)
                V.findViewById(R.id.ExpandableListView01);
```

`Fragment`s do not have a `findViewById()` method. You need to use your inflated `View` instead to get everything from your layout.

Also consider using Java naming conventions. Variables start with lowercase letters while Classes start with Uppercase letters.

Comment: Even if I replace this with V I get the error Cannot cast from View to CustomExpListView

Comment: Did you copy exactly as so? You still need the brackets after the so it looks like `=(CustomExpListView)`. You should clean your project if you're still getting that error, the cast should be right.

Comment: Also if cleaning doesn't work, are you absolutely **sure** that `CustomExpListView` extends `ListView` or `View`?

Comment: Yeah, I copied and pasted it over the existing code. I also cleaned the project. The error did not go away.

Comment: All I that would be wrong then is that `CustomExpListView` does not extend a View type. Mind posting the class (as your code has it) here?

Comment: Sure, I provided the PM_section and CustomExpListView classes http://pastebin.com/Dn1gvgQq

Comment: You are trying to cast an **`Activitiy`** into a **`View`**. Of course it won't work! They're completely different types! I think you need to read up on how Actitivities interact with views *before* attempting Fragments. Especially since you have a significant amount of code.

Comment: Oh... I am sorry. I was trying to implement a ExpandableListView within a fragment, and I could not extend ExpandableListActivity because it was already extending a fragment.

Comment: @user1927326 That's not the problem. The problem is that you are using **completely incompatible classes** An Activity will NEVER be a view. I suggest you learn how Java and OOP works, then try to understand the sample code **and afterwards** try to port to a Fragment. It's also the tut writers' fault - they named their class as `CustomizedListView` for an Activity shame on them.

Comment: @user1927326 Technically your code issue is resolved (in `onCreateView()` use the inflated view (`V` in your case) to access the layout views. Also, once you do *understand* what that code does and want to port to a Fragment, use a `ListFragment` instead - it will probably make life easier.

Answer (score 3):

Simply get the fragment's root view by calling `getView()` and then call `findViewById()` method:

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.ExpandableListView01);
```

Without it you will not be able to use `findViewById()` as `Fragment` class doesn't itself have such method.

Comment: Hmm, can you get the view with `getView()` *before* the fragment's `onCreateView()` has returned? Even if you could, it's a redundant method call, you already have your root view (`V`) available in the method.

Comment: I get this error when I implement   CustomExpListView custExpListView = (CustomExpListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ExpandableListView01); - Cannot cast from View to CustomExpListView

Comment: @A--C You're right, I didn't pay attention and didn't notice it's inside onCreateView() method, sorry. Of course A--C's answer is better in that case. Mine is more general.

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance, but how would this be set up? Do I place the custExpListView in onCreate? Would this get the view before the fragment's onCreateView()?

Comment: @user1927326 just replace `this` with `V` like in my answer and you should be good. With that said, no, `onCreate()` is called before `onCreateView()`. See the [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). From `onStart()` to `onStop()` and everything else in between you can use `getView()` since the root layout View is now **created**.

Comment: @user1927326 Exactly as A--C said, also in your case it's even a bit more efficient to use `V` instead of `getView()` as it gives you the same result, but faster because you have a direct access to the view.

Comment: @Mosquito OP was referencing an Activity not a View, hence the cast issues.