# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Unable to start activity ComponentInfo Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, undefined, undefined-reference

In the process of moving code from my main activity to an adapter I began experiencing an issue stating: `The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type VideosAdapter` and `The method getResources() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}`

I found this solution:

[The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448448/the-method-findviewbyidint-is-undefined-for-the-type)

However when I attempt to change this:

```
fav_up_btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);
```

to this:

```
fav_up_btn1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);
```

I end up with this:

```
v cannot be resolved
```

and I'm unsure how I should declare v in my case.

### JAVA:

```
public class VideosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
// The list of videos to display
List<Video> videos;
// An inflator to use when creating rows
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
Button fav_up_btn1;
Button fav_dwn_btn1;

/**
 * @param context this is the context that the list will be shown in - used to create new list rows
 * @param videos this is a list of videos to display
 */
public VideosAdapter(Context context, List<Video> videos) {
    this.videos = videos;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return videos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return videos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // If convertView wasn't null it means we have already set it to our list_item_user_video so no need to do it again
    if(convertView == null){
        // This is the layout we are using for each row in our list
        // anything you declare in this layout can then be referenced below
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_user_video, parent, false);
    }
    // We are using a custom imageview so that we can load images using urls
    // For further explanation see: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/imageview-with-loading-spinner/
    UrlImageView thumb = (UrlImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userVideoThumbImageView);

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userVideoTitleTextView); 
        fav_up_btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);

    fav_up_btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean favIsUp = fav_up_btn1
                    .getBackground()
                    .getConstantState()
                    .equals(getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.fav_up_btn1).getConstantState());
            // set the background
            fav_up_btn1
            .setBackgroundResource(favIsUp ? R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn1
                    : R.drawable.fav_up_btn1);
        }
    });

    // Get a single video from our list
    final Video video = videos.get(position);
    // Set the image for the list item
    thumb.setImageDrawable(video.getThumbUrl());
    // Set the title for the list item
    title.setText(video.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
fav_up_btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);
```

Within getView, it is elements within the View 'convertView' you are working with. In this case, that layout is list_item_user_video.xml

You say you are also having trouble with getResources(). That method requires a context (when you use it within an Activity, that context is implicit since an Activity is a context). However that's not the case within your adapter.

You are already accepting a context in your adapter constructor so keep a reference to it. Have a class level variable:

```
Context my_context;
```

Set it in the constructor:

```
public VideosAdapter(Context context, List<Video> videos) {
    this.videos = videos;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    my_context = context;
}
```

Then you can call getResources within your adapter using

```
my_context.getResources()
```

Comment: Or, if the entire Context isn't needed consider just keeping a reference to the Resources: my_resources = context.getResources();

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use `convertView` instead `v`:

```
fav_up_btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);
```

Comment: Thanks! That resolved the first issue! I still have the second error though: The method getResources() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}